# Class 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory' does not implement interface

Tags: android, apache

In my android app:
app/build.gradle

```
  android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 18
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 427
            versionName "2.1.427"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:ormlite:$AAVersion"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.7'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.1'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6'
    implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    implementation "org.androidannotations:ormlite-api:$AAVersion"

    implementation project(':fab')
    implementation project(':fointeraction')
    implementation project(':scanlib')

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
}
```

I use "**org.apache.http**" to create http requests.

When I start my app on Android 6.0 it's success start. 
And I success create http request and success get http response.
Nice.

```
url = https://some_host/
```

But when I start my ap on Android 9.0 I success create http request, but not return http response. Here errror:

```
Class 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory' does not implement interface 'org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactory' in call to 'java.net.Socket org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactory.createSocket(org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)' (declaration of 'org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator' appears in /data/app/com.myproject.app-fa20LoyoX_ze9Vk1tE46kg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
 java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory' does not implement interface 'org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactory' in call to 'java.net.Socket org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactory.createSocket(org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)' (declaration of 'org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator' appears in /data/app/com.myproject.app-fa20LoyoX_ze9Vk1tE46kg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at com.myproject.app.transport.lite.FOServiceLite.executeRequestLow(FOServiceLite.java:322)
    at com.myproject.app.transport.lite.FOServiceLite.loadApplicationProfileResponse(FOServiceLite.java:479)
    at com.myproject.app.transport.lite.FOServiceLite.executeCommand(FOServiceLite.java:494)
    at com.myproject.app.transport.lite.FOServiceLite.executeCommand(FOServiceLite.java:679)
    at com.myproject.app.service.ProviderService.sync(ProviderService.java:53)
    at com.myproject.app.fragment.SubscribesFragment.loadProviders(SubscribesFragment.java:73)
    at com.myproject.app.fragment.SubscribesFragment_.access$1801(SubscribesFragment_.java:23)
    at com.myproject.app.fragment.SubscribesFragment_$19.execute(SubscribesFragment_.java:291)
    at org.androidannotations.api.BackgroundExecutor$Task.run(BackgroundExecutor.java:405)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:459)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Here java snippet:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException;
import org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url.toString());
                    post.setEntity(be);
                    be = null;
                    // Reporting purpose
                    requestStartDate = new Date();
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);
                    post = null;
                    StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
```

error in this line:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);
```

Comment: Add

client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(
new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443)
);

above 

HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

Comment: I also facing same issue

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and putting this:

```
client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register( new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443) );
```

above the client.execute(post) line did solve my problem.

(credit: @Mandeep Singh in comment of original post)